# How to delete a message from Queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am using Rabbit MQ to replicate what `Jenkins` does.
The only issue I am facing is, lets say, when 10 messages are in queue. And there are some duplicate messages which are in `unacknowledged` state.
And I need to delete those messages from queue, how do I achieve this?

My rabbitmq configuration is as follows, where each queue only has one consumer. So if I have 10 messages, all will get processed through same consumer's thread.

```
Queue queue = new Queue(sfdcConnectionDetails.getGitRepoId() + "_" + sfdcConnectionDetails.getBranchConnectedTo(), true);
rabbitMqSenderConfig.amqpAdmin().declareQueue(queue);
rabbitMqSenderConfig.amqpAdmin().declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(new DirectExchange(byRepositoryRepositoryId.getRepository().getRepositoryId())).withQueueName());
RabbitMqConsumer container = new RabbitMqConsumer();
container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitMqSenderConfig.connectionFactory());
container.setQueueNames(queue.getName());
container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new ConsumerHandler(****, ***), new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter()));
container.startConsumers();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use any plugin (e.g [this](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication)) for deduplicating messages on the rabbit side.
2. Use cache on your consumer for detecting if the same message was processing recently.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by @ekiryuhin, One of the approach you could take is assign a request_id tag it to the payload before producing message to RabbitMQ & on your consumer's end cache the request_id. Look out for the request_id if already present ignore payload and delete it.
This request_id might work as deduplication-id for your payloads.